# resourceAdapter config properties for WMQ 7.5 taking defaults instead of specified configs

Tags: ibm-mq, wildfly

I have a resource adapter for Websphere MQ 7.5

```
             <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/ctm/ConnectionFactory" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                         <config-property name="hostName">
                            devel.comp.net
                        </config-property>

                        <config-property name="username">
                            mqm
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="channel">
                            COMP.DIR.SVRCONN
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="password">
                            mqm
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="transportType">
                            CLIENT
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">
                            devel.queue.manager
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="port">
                            1414
                        </config-property>        
                        <security>
                            <application/>
                        </security>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
```

If i change the port number to 2414 then it picks up these properties but if i do not change the port number it defaults to 1414 localhost and queumanager name   '' as if taking defaults. Can any one tell me what is wrong in this.

once I revert the port number from 2414 to 1414, it starts taking deafults and when i change it back to 2414 it takes the hostname and queue manager name correctly.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt figure out how and why was the port change would make the properties to be loaded. instead, I used the systemproperties in standlaone-full.xml

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="websphere.hostName" value="devel.comps.net"/>
        <property name="websphere.port" value="1414"/>
        <property name="websphere.channel" value="BLOBBER.DIR.SVRCONN"/>
        <property name="websphere.transportType" value="CLIENT"/>
        <property name="websphere.queueManager" value="devel.queue.manager"/>
```

and enabled it

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:3.0">            
      <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
</subsystem>
```

then used the ejb-jar.xml to identify which properties i need to use

```
     <message-driven>
                  <ejb-name>MyAppInboundBean</ejb-name>
                  <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
                  <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
                  <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
                  <activation-config>
                      <activation-config-property>
                          <activation-config-property-name>
                              destinationType
                          </activation-config-property-name>
                          <activation-config-property-value>
                              javax.jms.Queue
                          </activation-config-property-value>
                      </activation-config-property>
                      <activation-config-property>
                          <activation-config-property-name>
                              destination
                          </activation-config-property-name>
                          <activation-config-property-value>
                              java:/myapp/FromCTM
                          </activation-config-property-value>
                      </activation-config-property>
 <activation-config-property>
                      <activation-config-property-name>
                          hostName
                      </activation-config-property-name>
                      <activation-config-property-value>${websphere.hostName}</activation-config-property-value>
                  </activation-config-property>
                  <activation-config-property>
                      <activation-config-property-name>
                          queueManager
                      </activation-config-property-name>
                      <activation-config-property-value>${websphere.queueManager}</activation-config-property-value>
                  </activation-config-property>
```